# Is there any OPRF (oblibivious pseudo random random functions) between one receiver (1 input) and n senders (n inputs)? any references to read?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, multiparty-computation, oblivious-transfer

I am looking for some references for multi-party / distributed Oblivious pseudorandom Functions.

I found two party OPRF protocols between a sender $S$ and a receiver $R$ for securely computing a pseudorandom function $f_k()$ relying on the key $k$ computed by $S$ and on input $x$ contributed by $R$, such that $R$ learns only the value $f_k(x)$ while $S$ learns nothing from the interaction.

I am looking for a function, such that the resulting output gathered by $R$ is defined such that $f_{h(n, k)} (x)$, where $h(n,k)$ is function that depends on the $n$ secret inputs of n senders.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi! Welcome to crypto.SE! You can put dollar sign around your maths, then it renders as it does in LaTeX. I took the liberty to do that for you.

Sadly, I think this question will be closed because we generally want questions that can be answered, instead of giving "endless" listings of references/literature. Literature requests are off topic.

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for editing my question content and for ansewring.

Comment: One solution to your problem might be evaluating the PRF in an MPC protocol and then attach the corresponding input/output wires - Maybe there is some work done on multiparty OPRFs but generic MPC should do the job in case you don't find any better solutions.

Comment: Thanks Dragos, for your comment. This can effectively help me to resolve my problem.